# How to edit the html content template?

Tags: template, theme

Here's an example with the About page:

```
<div class="col-main">
  <div class="std">
    //First line of content entered into UI content editor
```

When looking inside my 2columns-right.phtml:

```
<div class="col-main">
  <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
```

So this tells me this `<div class="std">` is somewhere in some template. I've tried grepping my entire Magento directory and find only references under product/view.phtml, list.phtml, and description.phtml. None of these are used for the CMS pages and so I'm at a loss for where I can find these content templates.

The end goal is finding where I can edit the templates to remove unwanted elements like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is in this bit of XML inside of `base/default/layout/cms.xml`:

```
<cms_page translate="label">
    ...
    <reference name="content">
        ...
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="cms.wrapper" translate="label">
            ...
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>std</value></action>
            <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_page>
```

The wrapper block adds a `<div>` you are looking for and `setElementClass` method sets the `std` class on it.

**UPDATE**

To remove the wrapper "correct" way within `local.xml` file of your custom theme you have to move `cms_page` block directly to `content` block using `unsetChild`/`remove` routine and then `remove`cms.wrapper` block.

Comment: Ah good to know. Thanks. Do you know if I just remove the `<action>` it will remove the div and not mess everything up?

Comment: Please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

Just to help some poeple how don't know how to add the code. We have 2 option

Option 1

local.xml as Tim said, see link to know how to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103834/how-to-remove-std-div-in-magento

Option 2

Insert this code inside the cms layout you want to disable the div class="std" tag:

```
<reference name="content">
<action method="unsetChild">
  <alias>cms.wrapper</alias>
</action>
  <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
</reference>
```